# RSS Feed post not fetching upto 2017 in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I have a problem with RSS Feed in wordpress.

By default, the MAGPIE_CACHE_ON of wordpress is set to true and because of that all my rss feed post of 2017 will not be fetch. It will only fetch all the post upto 2016 only.

If I set the MAGPIE_CACHE_ON to false (define('MAGPIE_CACHE_ON', false)) in the wp-config, it will be able to fetch all my RSS Feed post upto 2017 but there is a problem. It will make my whole website much slower.

Is there another way to fetch all my RSS feed post upto 2017 without adding the line define('MAGPIE_CACHE_ON', false) in the wp-config? Please advise.